# Initialize TinyMCE editor / visual editor after AJAX insert

Tags: ajax, tinymce, editor

I have a "repeater" style field group on a custom options page. There's an active visual editor in a hidden state, and when the user clicks "add new" the whole row is cloned. I then need to initialize the visual editor in the cloned row. My code:

```
$('.repeater-add-new').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('repeater');
    $( '#' + target).find('.repeater-row:not(.clone) .repeater-content.in').collapse();
    var newRow = $( '#' + target + ' .repeater-row.clone' ).clone().appendTo( '#' + target + ' .repeater-row-wrapper' ).removeClass('clone');
    rebuildIndex(target);

    // Initialize editors if needed
    newRow.find('.wp-editor-wrap').each(function(index, el) {
        var ed_id = $(this).find('textarea').attr('id');

        tinymce.init(tinyMCEPreInit.mceInit[ed_id]);
        tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, ed_id); 
        quicktags({id : ed_id});
    });
});
```

Screenshot of the interface:

[image: Screenshot]

When the page loads, I get the console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onpageload' of undefined

And of course the editor doesn't work. After I save the page it works fine of course, but I need it to be functional when the row is added as well.

Comment: did you get solution to the problem 'onpageload'

Comment: It looks like you may also need to register some things with quick tags. I'm not 100% sure as I can't test this locally, but you could start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519322/load-wordpress-wp-editor-dynamically-ajax to see if that helps at all.

Comment: Hey, came across this again. OP, can you please add a snippet for how to add one of these fields to the post editor? I can try and repro this locally and dig into it if you can provide a way to stand this up myself.

Comment: Hey @phatskat, thanks. I actually ended up going a different direction entirely... the client wanted to package this system for commercial sale so we re-wrote everything using a custom interface without ACF. Appreciate the offer to help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you manage to get the editor working without your javascript included? If so try to create a template what includes a working tinymce editor and then rewrite your javascript to copy that template using the `WithDataAndEvents` argument of the jQuery [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function set to true.

For example:

```
$('.cloner').click(function(){
  $('.container').append($('.template').clone(true).removeClass('hidden'));
});
```